Combine Array Elements Into One Index
I've list of strings where I've data as follows:
[0] - A
[1] - B
[2] - C

If the list has more than one element, I can do the following to count:
int val = item.Count; //item is the list of string object

Now I am trying to do something like this and not pretty sure if that's possible to do, I am iterating the list at a time, my requirement is as follows:
[0] - A
[1] - B
[2] - C

To:
[0] - ABC //Later I can get the length of three

I can do the following but expecting it to get done in one go:
string str = "";

foreach(var list in item) //Rather iterating with foreach loop, in one go get the total count of the first index, later the second index
{
   str += list;
}


string.Join? Or what would be element with index [1] in the new list?

You can do a count on a list withy zero, one, or more elements. Why do you say you can do it when it has more than one element?

You can use String.Concat:
item = new List<string>{ String.Concat(item) };

Not sure if it is a List<string> or string[], but the approach should be clear
